# lightning-formatted-number deosn’t show correct currency code for some users

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning, currency

I have used lightning-formatted-number like below in one of my LWC

```
<lightning-formatted-number class="slds-text-align_left" value={someVariable} format-style="currency"></lightning-formatted-number>
```

In org **Company Information** setup, I have set **Currency Locale** to **CAD**.

For some users this is working fine and I can see **CA$** prefix for the currency.
While for some other users (users which were already present before the Currency Locale change) its not working as expected, I can see **$** instead of **CA$**.

For debugging I tried hardcoding attribute `currency-code="CAD"` and still the CA$ was not populated for these users.

Comment: does your org have multi-currency enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find how to remove **CA** before **$**.

Instead, I use the following code:

```
<!-- YourComponent.html -->
<template>
    {formattedCurrency}
</template>

// YourComponent.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class YourComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api someVariable;

    get formattedCurrency() {            
        const formattedValue = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'USD',
            maximumFractionDigits: 2,
        }).format(someVariable);
        return formattedValue;
    }
}
```