# lightning-formatted-number shows "US$" instead of "$" as currency code

Tags: lightning-web-components, currency, lightning-formatted-number

I use `lightning-formatted-number` to show Item Amount on my **LWC**.

And I have a **multicurrency** enabled in my org.

So I pass the `currencyCode` dynamically to `lightning-formatted-number` see:

```html
<lightning-formatted-number 
    value={item.amount} 
    format-style="currency" 
    currency-code={item.currencyCode} 
    currency-display-as="symbol"
></lightning-formatted-number>
```

Where `item.currencyCode` is either `GBP` or `USD`.

So for `GBP` I see correct `£` symbol,
However for the `USD` I am seeing `US$` as **currency-symbol**.

Currency Configs:

- **Corporate Currency** : **British Pound**
- **Activate Multiple Currencies** - **enabled**
- **Advanced Currency Management** is **not enabled**
- **Parenthetical Currency Conversion** is **enabled**
- **User Currency**: **USD - U.S. Dollar**

Active Currencies:

- GBP - British Pound - Corporate
- USD - U.S. Dollar

I couldn't find anything in the docs for [lightning-formatted-number](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-number/example).

Here are similar question: [lightning-formatted-number deosn’t show correct currency code for some users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/393089/lightning-formatted-number-deosn-t-show-correct-currency-code-for-some-users), however there is no answer

Do I **miss something** or it is **corrected behavior** ?

As I would want to show the `$` as **currency-symbol**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appeared changing **User Locale** to **English (United States)** fixed it.

**Previous** User locale: **English (United Kingdom)**
**Updated** User locale: **English (United States)**

To change it go: **User Settings** => **My Personal Information** => **Language & Time Zone** => **Locale**

[image]

See [Edit Your Language and Locale Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.usersetup_lang_time_zone.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 1):

It's the expected behavior. `lightning-formatted-number` component leveages [`Intl.NumberFormat(locale, options)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) to format numbers and the currency symbol depends upon `locale` attribute.
Since GBP is the corporate currency, I guess the default locale of the Salesforce org is *English (United Kingdom)*, so `en-GB`, therefore you could try the following code that shows `US$` as currency-symbol:

```js
const optionsUSD = { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', currencyDisplay: 'symbol' };
const optionsGBP = { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP', currencyDisplay: 'symbol' };
const locale = 'en-GB';
const usdNumberFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, optionsUSD);
const gbpNumberFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, optionsGBP);
const number = 123456.78;
console.log(usdNumberFormatter.format(number)); // US$123,456.78
console.log(gbpNumberFormatter.format(number)); // £123,456.78
```

That component import the `locale` via `import locale from '@salesforce/i18n/locale';` so you cannot force it.

If you want to show the `$` as currency-symbol, you should build your own component that accept the same paramenters and the locale one.
If you need just a method it could be something like:

```js
#formatters = {};

getCurrencyFormatter(currency) {
    let formatter = this.#formatters[currency];
    if (!formatter) {
        const locale = 'en-US';
        const options = { style: 'currency', currency, currencyDisplay: 'symbol' };
        formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, options);
        this.#formatters[currency] = formatter;
    }
    return formatter;
}

format(currency, value) {
    const formatter = getCurrencyFormatter(currency);
    return formatter.format(value);
}
```

Then calling `format(item.currencyCode, item.amount)` results in the desired output

Comment: Thanks, however it is too much work and we use it in a lot of places. Changing the User Locale helped.